# create ad enterprise geodatabase with ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis, arcobjects

I am new to ArcObjects programming and i want to create an enterprise Geodatabase.
In ArcMap , simply use tools to create a database. how can I do this with ArcObjects?
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the geoprocessing framework. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an ArcObjects class for the [Create Enterprise Geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000162000000) tool, so you might need to [write a Python script](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_tools_in_Python/002z0000000n000000/) that calls that tool, add the script to a toolbox, and then use the [ArcObjects geoprocessing framework](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Using_geoprocessing/0001000004mm000000/) to call the script.